# IndexError: list index out of range even with a perfect input read file

Tags: python, text-parsing, indexoutofrangeexception, csv, index-error

Python version 2.7.13, main.py

```
import csv
with open(r"int.txt") as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
   d = list(reader)
print d[1][1]
```

int.txt file is as below

```
1   577 7
7   85  888
0   86  876
```

I want print d[1][1] to return 85, but it throws the following error.

```
sh-4.4$ python main.py                                                                                                                                                                                        
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                        
    print d[1][1]                                                                                                                                                                                             
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated. I made sure to check that the text file has no blank lines, referencing similar questions.

Comment: That doesn't look tab-delimited to me.

Comment: I put tabs in the obvious places, and got a very nice `'85'1 as the result.  I don't know that you have tabs in the supplied file.

Answer (score 1):

Your text file is not tab-delimited. Either change your delimiter to specific white space or change your .txt file to have a tab between each number.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that using the Tab key, on the keyboard won't necessarily delimit my text file. Now, I've put it into excel and copied into text, which gives me the proper output.

Comment: If this helped you, how about selecting it as the answer that helped you!